# Does the usual filtration on graded objects satisfy a universal property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, abelian-categories, graded-modules

Let $\mathsf{A}$ be an abelian category, such as $R \mathsf{Mod}$ for concreteness. We can think of the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded objects in $\mathsf{A}$ as the functor category $\mathsf{A}^\mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ is viewed as a discrete category. This works for $\mathbb{N}$-gradings as well.

The category of filtered objects in $\mathsf{A}$ in the classical sense may (potentially) be too small, so we can allow "generalized" filtrations as [Nicolas Schmidt](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263/what-is-the-universal-property-of-associated-graded) suggested in his answer to a related question. Then the generalized filtrations are the objects of the functor category $\mathsf{A}^{(\mathbb{Z}, \leq)}$, where $(\mathbb{Z}, \leq)$ is the ordered group of integers viewed as a poset category. We could of course use the poset $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$ instead if we need to.

Now, given an a graded object $A$ we can form the corresponding filtered object with pieces $A^{(n)} = \bigoplus_{i \leq n} A_i$. This is obviously a functor from graded objects in $\mathsf{A}$ to filtered objects in $\mathsf{A}$. Indeed, given a morphism $f: A \to B$ of graded objects, which we write in degree $i$ as $f_i: A_i \to B_i$, the corresponding morphism of filtered objects is the obvious one $f^{(n)} := \bigoplus_{i \leq n} f_i : A^{(n)} \to B^{(n)}$.

Now, does this "filtration" functor satisfy a universal property? That is, does it have a left or right adjoint?

Comment: Your definition of $\overline{f}_j$ doesn't make sense: the $f_i(x_i)$ aren't even elements of $B_j$ for $i<j$.  You need to map them into $B_j$ via the $b$ maps.

Comment: Ah good point! It was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us call your functor $F$.  Then $F$ is left adjoint to the functor $G:\mathsf{A}^{(\mathbb{Z},\leq)}\to \mathsf{A}^\mathbb{Z}$ which is just composition with the inclusion functor $i:\mathbb{Z}\to(\mathbb{Z},\leq)$.  That is, $G$ takes a filtered object to the graded object whose graded pieces are the objects in the filtration.

This is straightforward to check directly, but you can also see it by some general nonsense.  Indeed, the left adjoint to $G$ is by definition the functor that takes a functor $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathsf{A}$ to its left Kan extension along the inclusion $i:\mathbb{Z}\to(\mathbb{Z},\leq)$.  Your formula for $F$ is then just the usual [colimit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kan_extension#Kan_extensions_as_.28co.29limits) for computing left Kan extensions: to compute the left Kan extension of $T:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathsf{A}$ at an object $n\in(\mathbb{Z},\leq)$, you form the colimit of the diagram formed by objects $T(m)$ indexed by the comma category $(i\downarrow n)$.  That comma category is just the discrete category of all $m\leq n$, so this colimit is your direct sum $\bigoplus_{m\leq n} T(m)$.

(Of course, there is nothing special about $\mathbb{Z}$ here--the same thing would work for any poset.)

Comment: Thanks! I am also curious, if you happen to know the answer: does this filtration functor also preserve tensor products (the "correct" tensors for graded and filtered objects)? I have a feeling it should.

Comment: What tensor products do you have in mind exactly?

Comment: I know that chain complexes have a tensor product, and since chain complexes are a subcategory of my category of generalized filtrations, I figured that the same construction should be the "correct" tensor product on filtrations. The tensor product on graded objects would be the usual one.

Comment: If you define the tensor product of filtrations by the same formula as the usual tensor product of graded objects ($(A\otimes B)_n=\bigoplus_{i+j=n}A_i\otimes B_j)$), then $F$ does not preserve the tensor product.  For instance, if $A$ is a graded object concentrated in degrees $0$ and $1$, then $F(A\otimes A)_1=A_0\otimes A_0\oplus A_0\otimes A_1\oplus A_1\otimes A_0$, but $(F(A)\otimes F(A))_1=A_0\otimes A_0\oplus A_0\otimes A_0\oplus A_0\otimes A_1\oplus A_1\otimes A_0$.

Comment: If you want $F$ to preserve the tensor product, I think you need to make the tensor product on filtered objects take a colimit: if $i+j<n$, then there are multiple ways that $A_i\otimes B_j$ maps into $(A\otimes B)_n$, one for each $i'\geq i$ and $j'\geq j$ such that $i'+j'=n$.  You want to coequalize all of these.  I believe it should be possible to interpret this as a Day convolution.

Comment: Ah I see; I was just hoping the canonical filtrationt would preserve tensor products so that it would preserve monoid objects, and hence take graded algebras to filtered algebras

Comment: Well, the usual definition of "filtered algebra" in the case that the maps are all injective should be compatible with the coequalized tensor product of filtered objects I described above.  So you should still get that $F$ sends graded algebras to filtered algebras in a useful sense.

Comment: Ah, OK so then it works out nicely!

Comment: Probably the fact that $F$ preserves these tensor products is a special case of a general fact that left Kan extension preserves Day convolutions, though I haven't sorted out the details of why that would be true.

Comment: Cool, that's good to know. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I was attempting to prove that the adjunction holds (showing that the appropriate hom-sets are naturally in bijection), but I ran into an issue, which I have explained in an edit to my post. Based on this, it seems that the adjunction only holds with "classical" filtrations where the maps are inclusions. Maybe I'm making a silly mistake somewhere?